# Postgresql trigger funciton seems to prevent insertion of any record

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, triggers

I am a Postgresql newb.

I created a function to check if an INSERT tries to create the same value in two different tables.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_pids_not_equal()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
begin 
if exists (select *
from cards c , echecks e
where c.pid = e.pid)
then
raise NOTICE 'Must have different PID than entry in cards.pid';
end if;
return null;
end
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

I assigned the trigger in this manner:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_cards_pids_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON cards
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_pids_not_equal();
```

Now, whenever I try to do any insert of record on Cards table, I always get `INSERT 0 0` with no error messages -- even if the record is clearly a bad record with missing columns or wrong column types.

Any ideas as to the culprit? Also, how do show more error reports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `return new` if you want to insert record, something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_pids_not_equal()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
begin 
    if exists (select * from cards c, echecks e where c.pid = e.pid) then
        raise NOTICE 'Must have different PID than entry in cards.pid';
        return null;
    end if;
    return new;
end
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Comment: That fixed the issue with INSERT (I can insert records), but when I inserted into table Echecks a pid that already existed in Cards pid, the insertion still completed, i.e. the trigger did not prevent the insertion and raise notice as desired.

Comment: don't know what you `exists` check should do. Anyway, you can use `new.pid` to get `pid` for current inserting record

Comment: Thank you. I needed to use new.pid keyword. I was trying to use the cards.pid as a reference, but then your comment made me realize the trigger works before insert. Therefore the cards.pid was not in the referenced table yet. Much obliged.