# How to implement a constraint in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, constraints

In a Details table (Product ID, Receipt ID) only products with a stock greater than 0 can be added.
Warehouse (Product ID, Stock). How can I implement this constraint in Postgresql?

Comment: So when a record is added to the `Details` table, you want to check the stock available in the `Warehouse` table, is that correct?

Answer (score -1):

```
-- CREATE THE FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION trg_product_stock_check()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
  if exists (select * from warehouse w where w.product_id = new.product_id and stock <= 0) then
    raise NOTICE 'Product must have a stock of greater than 0';
    return null;
  end if;
  return new;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- CREATE THE TRIGGER
CREATE TRIGGER product_stock_check
BEFORE INSERT ON "orders"
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_product_stock_check();
```

The solution is to create a trigger function that's set up on insert of the order's table. First create your function. You want to check your warehouse table for the product's stock quantity in the function. If the product's stock quantity is less than or equal to 0, return null with a log message. Otherwise, return the newly created row (eg: the `new` keyword in the function is the row being inserted). After you create the function, you can set the trigger up to run on the orders table before insert.

You can read more about creating a trigger/function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22736148/1913185) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20200053/1913185).

Comment: Let me explain better, I have an order table and an order detail table. when I insert an item in detail this must have a positive quantity in stock otherwise I cannot enter details.

Comment: Ah, I think you're looking for a trigger on insert?

Comment: Yeah but I don't know what to write (I'm a noob)

Comment: @antonio - updated answer with how to write a trigger